# how to add "L" literal prefix to add_definition in cmake

Tags: cmake

I wanted to append L literal prefix to c++ macro with cmake `add_definitions`

I wanted to build like below "FIX" macro.

```
#define FIX L"D:/test/test"
```

so I tried

```
add_definitions("-DFIX=L\"\"D:/test/test\"")
```

I think it is right. but result was very weird.

this is my result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czh6D.png)

as you can see, it correctly makes L"D:/test/test"

but it was appended other macro options what I didn't concatenated on back of string. I don't know why they appended to my macro.( for example \DWIN32)

I also tried many things. but I didn't find right solution yet.

could you give me a advice?

thank you.

I tried to find question on the internet community

but there was no solution.

so I tried

`add_definitions("-DFIX=L\"\"D:/test/test\"")`
`add_definitions(-DFIX=L\"D:/test/test")`
`add_definitions("-DFIX=L\"D:/test/test\"")`

but they was not a solution.

Comment: instead of a screenshot of an IDE's hover info of a definition, please show the generated compiler flag.

Comment: what if you do `add_definitions([[-DFIX=L"D:/test/test]])`? see also https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument

Comment: I don't know how to see generated compiler flag in visual studio cmake. I finally solved. but it didn't used cmake. 
```#if UNICODE
#define concat(x,y) x#y
#define FIX concat(L, FIX)
#endif // UNICODE
```
I define several additional macro in my code.

Comment: `but it was appended other macro options` Please post the output of cmake configuration, what generator are you using, what cmake options and version are you using, please post the verbose (`make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake --build <dir> --verbose`) full verbatim whole output of building of your project. At best, please create a small [MCVE].

Comment: @fabyday if you found a solution, please post an answer instead of a comment. SO encourages self-answers. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I was failed. (that was confusing me. I guess it was ide make wrong infos)@KamilCuk@friedrich
if I found solution I'll try to write own solution on here.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the compile definition as it is. No `-D`. No extra quotes.

```
add_compile_definitions(FIX=L"D:/test/test")
```

Command `add_definitions` has been superseded by `add_compile_definition`. See CMake docs. Over `add_compile_definitions` prefer `target_compile_definitions`.

MCVE:

```
#CmakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test)
add_executable(main main.c)
target_compile_definitions(main PUBLIC FIX=L"D:/test/test")

#main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t *s = FIX;
    printf("%ls\n", s);
}

# output
$ cmake -S. -Bbuild && cmake --build build && ./build/main 
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: ../build
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable main
[100%] Built target main
D:/test/test
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. but I finally found my solution and I works well. It is done by your help. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

before I tell solution.

I appreciate with your kind answer :)
@kamilCuk @Friedrich @starball

I just finally founded my solution

```
add_definitions(-DFIX=L\"\"D:/test/test\"\")
```

It clearly shows L"D/test/test".

I think "" is keyword expression. I don't know why exactly.

when I appended L to predefined literal, quotes are gone somewhere.

so many kind answer tell me a solution. it doesn't work for me. I don't know why? is it version is wrong? (my version is 3.20.3 cmake)